# Undefined method for nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to finish the codecademy ruby on rails track. I'm getting this error:

```
Showing /home/ccuser/workspace/learn-rails_innovation-cloud/innovation
cloud/app/views/signups/new.html.erb where line #41 raised:

undefined method `content' for #<Signup id: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil,        updated_at: nil>
Extracted source (around line #41):

      <%= form_for(@signup) do |f| %>  
          <div class="field"> 
            <%= f.label :message %><br> 
            <%= f.text_area :content %> 
          </div> 
          <div class="actions"> 
            <%= f.submit "Create" %>
```

Here's my controller:

```
        class SignupsController < ApplicationController

            def new
                @signup = Signup.new
            end

        end
```

And finally my migration file:

```
class CreateSignups < ActiveRecord::Migration
              def change
                create_table :signups do |t|
                  t.text :email
                  t.timestamps
                end
              end
end
```

Any insight is appreciated to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You don't have a **content** field in your `Signup Model`. Change `<%= f.text_area :content %>` to `<%= f.text_field :email %>` **or** add a column named **content** in Signup table

Comment: give url at form_for

Comment: @Abhi THANK YOU! I tried adding content as a column at some point, but it kept throwing the same error. Changing the text_field to :email worked though.

Answer (score 0):

**content** field is missing in your **signups** table. Please add using migration.

Comment: I tried adding but it gave me the same error. @abhi solution worked though. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Your form code should look like:

```
<%= form_for(@signup) do |f| %>  
    <div class="field"> 
        <%= f.label :email %><br> 
        <%= f.text_field :email %> 
    </div> 
    <div class="actions"> 
<%= f.submit "Create" %>
```

And it should work now.